# Retrieving data from Firebase is not working android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently new to Android and Firebase developing. The issue is that I can send data to Realtime Database, however when I want to retrieve the information back to the app, nothing is happening. I'm not getting any errors when compiling. If someone could advise, much appreciated

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button edButton;
    TextView Name;
    TextView Email;
    TextView Age;
    TextView AboutMe;
    Button reButton;

    FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;

    DatabaseReference mDbRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile/User");

        Name = findViewById(R.id.NameTextView);
        Age = findViewById(R.id.AgeTextView);
        Email = findViewById(R.id.EmailTextView);
        AboutMe = findViewById(R.id.AboutMeTextView);
        edButton = findViewById(R.id.editButton);
        reButton = findViewById(R.id.reButton);


        edButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditProfile.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        reButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mDbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile/User");

                mDbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        String name = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue();
                        String age = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Age").getValue();
                        String email = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Email").getValue();
                        String aboutMe = (String) dataSnapshot.child("AboutMe").getValue();

                        Name.setText(name);
                        Age.setText(age);
                        Email.setText(email);
                        AboutMe.setText(aboutMe);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });


            }
        });


    }
}
```

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDP5S.png)

Comment: kindly attach error log or error message along with question

Comment: i guess issue is that you are attaching database listener in `reButton` button click call after that button clicks your data will show